# Not able to run the Hive sql via Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to execute hive SQL via spark code but it is throwing below mentioned error. I can only select data from hive table.

My spark version is 1.6.1
My Hive version is 1.2.1

command to run spark submit

spark-submit --master local[8] --files /srv/data/app/spark/conf/hive-site.xml test_hive.py

code:-

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
    sc=SparkContext()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    HiveContext = HiveContext(sc)
    #HiveContext.setConf("yarn.timeline-service.enabled","false")
    #HiveContext.sql("SET spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=false")
    HiveContext.sql("use default")
    HiveContext.sql("TRUNCATE TABLE default.test_table")
    HiveContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/srv/data/data_files/*' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE default.test_table")
    df = HiveContext.sql("select * from version")

    for x in df.collect():
            print x

Error:-


17386 [Thread-3] ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper  -
======================
HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
SET spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed=true
SET spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect=true
SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false
SET spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=800
SET spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=true
SET spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.partitionPruning=true
SET spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
SET spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=false
OK
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.6.2-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.6.2-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class

======================
END HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iip/hist_load.py", line 10, in <module>
    HiveContext.sql("TRUNCATE TABLE default.tbl_wmt_pos_file_test")

 File "/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
  File "/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.6.2-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/srv/data/OneClickProvision_1.2.2/files/app/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.6.2-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.6.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
```

Comment: Added a possible solution. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

> I can only select data from hive table.

It is perfectly normal and expected behavior. Spark SQL is not intended to be fully compatible with HiveQL or implement full set of features provided by Hive.

Overall, some compatibility is preserved, but is not guaranteed to be kept in the future, as Spark SQL converges to SQL 2003 standard.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for input.
I am able to execute insert and select statement from spark-thrift server which uses same Spark SQL Module.
is there any other parameter we need to change to access table?

Answer (score 0):

From the [post here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/101145/spark-job-failure-with-javalanglinkageerror-classc.html):

Spark job fails with `ClassCastException` because of conflict in different version of same class in `YARN` and `SPARK` jar.

From Set below property in HiveContext:

```
hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hc.setConf("yarn.timeline-service.enabled","false")
```

Comment: Hi Gyan,
Thanks,
I tried to setConf opetion for timeline-service but still i am getting error.